# How to write python dictionary to the csv file in sql databases format?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, io, export-to-csv

What I want to do is to have keys of the first dictionary on the first row and the values of each dictionary  be under the first row. like a sql table

something like this :

```
title  | director  |  year | genre
movie1   director1   1999    Drama
movie2   director2   2001    Fantasy
movie3   director3   2018    Action
movie4   director4   2011    Adventure
```

here is the code :

```
from imdb import IMDb
import csv
from datetime import datetime

startTime = datetime.now()

movie_id = 1
for i in range(1, 6):
    movie = ia.get_movie(movie_id)
    movie_id += i

    print(datetime.now() - startTime)
    print (movie_id)
    print ('\n')

    with open('dict.csv', 'a') as csv_file:
        writer = csv.writer(csv_file)

        for key, value in movie.items():
            writer.writerow([key, value])
```

here in each loop each dictionary will be appended to csv

Comment: Have you seen [`csv.DictWriter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter) ?